# Preloading website images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image preloading script which loads all the images with a loading bar

Once all the images are loaded it will then show the entire website.

**Problem**

The percentage stops at 80%.

---

See here for example: [nanomitetech.com/projects/stillmens/preloading.html](http://nanomitetech.com/projects/stillmens/preloading.html)

---

**JS**

```
(function ($) {
    var imgList = [];
    $.extend({
        preload: function (imgArr, option) {
            var setting = $.extend({
                init: function (loaded, total) {},
                loaded: function (img, loaded, total) {},
                loaded_all: function (loaded, total) {}
            }, option);
            var total = imgArr.length;
            var loaded = 0;

            setting.init(0, total);
            for (var i in imgArr) {
                imgList.push($("<img />")
                    .attr("src", imgArr[i])
                    .load(function () {
                    loaded++;
                    setting.loaded(this, loaded, total);
                    if (loaded == total) {
                        setting.loaded_all(loaded, total);
                    }
                }));
            }
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: http://nanomitetech.com/projects/stillmens/preloading.html
above is the test link

Comment: Code "looks good to me". How about a demo? Link a jsFiddle?

Comment: What happens to the script if the image is not found on the server? In the network tab I can see a 404.

Comment: You have 2 404s and `.localScroll()` is not defined.

Comment: good preloaders handle errors better than stopping everything....

Answer (score 3):

One of your images in your array has the wrong src:

```
http://nanomitetech.com/projects/stillmens/images/benefits.png.png
```

Should be:

```
http://nanomitetech.com/projects/stillmens/images/benefits.png
```

This precludes the image from loading, so your load event listener doesn't get called for this broken image, and your `loaded` counter doesn't increment.

4/5 successful image loads = 80%

Comment: great chris. it worked perfectly when i remove extra .png from image.

Comment: Just looked at the site and it looks like the OP fixed the code, it loaded fine for me.